# How to enlarge matrix by repeating matrix rows?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

Initial matrix is `A = [ [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`. Every row is to be replicated 3 times such that the output matrix is

```
B = [1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 3;4 5 6; 4 5 6; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 7 8 9; 7 8 9]
B = replicate(permute(A,[3 2 1]),3,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean like that?

```
kron(A,ones(3,1))
```

ans =

```
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 4     5     6
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
 7     8     9
 7     8     9
```

Answer (score 2):

Since **R2015a**, there is a dedicated function for this: [**`repelem`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html).

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
B = repelem(A,3,1)
```

---

```
B =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     4     5     6
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
     7     8     9
     7     8     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just indexing:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]; % original matrix
m = 3; % row repetition factor
n = 1; % column repetition factor
B = A(ceil(1/m:1/m:size(A,1)), ceil(1/n:1/n:size(A,2)));
```